# Remove group ID from user

Tags: users, group

How can I remove a group (which was previously deleted) from a user which still references it? If I run `groups`, I get an error about a non-existent group:

```
$ groups
myuser dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev fuse lpadmin sambashare groups: cannot find name for group ID 1001
1001
```

The usual way of using `deluser` doesn't work because the group name no longer exists and there seems to be no flag for using IDs:

```
$ deluser myuser 1001
The group `1001' does not exist.
```

Is there a more straight forward way to remove a group (by ID) from a user other than by recreating the group, deleting the group from the user, and then redeleting the group?

Comment: There's still the easy fix: recreate the group (`--uid=1001`), remove it from the user's groups, and delete it again.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith No, that wouldn't change anything. The group is  deleted, so the user is no longer in the group. The user's running processes are in the group, that's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groups` show you the groups you are in. So the problem is that your process thinks you still are in the now deleted 1001 group, from the `deluser myuser 1001` command.

You still would get that error message from `groups` as long as the process you started thinks you are in the group. When doing these kind of things in `bash` for my own account, I normally start a new shell to make sure that things are as I want them to be in that shell.

In your case starting a new shell should solve the issue, if not then the group would still exists in `/etc/group` and then `deluser` would not complain.

Comment: Any idea about how to handle it in CentoOS ?  `deluser` doesn't seem to exist, and `userdel` doesn't work.  Finally, `gpasswd` apparently doesn't handle group ids...

Comment: @anto It is completely unclear what mean by 'it' in your comment? Do you mean you cannot handle restarting the shell? In the OP's question the group is already deleted, whether done `deluser`, `gppasswd` or `userdel` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: "It" = op's question = "remove a group (which was previously deleted) from a user which still references it".  I had the exact same issue under Centos, but `deluser` doesn't exist there, so I couldn't follow your solution.  But I've finally solved it by re-creating the group and then removing it.

Comment: I have the same problem but even when opening a new shell the problem persists. Also, I can confirm that the group is not in`/etc/group`. Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

you can remove the reference to the group manually i.e. modify /etc/group

Comment: He's already done that.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, my bad.